# Use a dict to access nested instances of classes in Python

Tags: python, namespaces, nested-attributes

I'm trying to define an attribute in a nested class and then access it later using a string or maybe a list of strings.  Here's code for what I'm trying to do

```
class MyNestedClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.att1 = 5.

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_nested_inst = MyNestedClass()

my_inst = MyClass()
```

I want to change the value of `my_inst.my_nested_inst.att1` when all I have is a list like this: `my_list = ['my_inst','my_nested_inst','att1']`.

If I use this:

```
vars(vars(vars()[my_list[0]])[my_list[1]])[my_list[2]]
```

This works, but the problem is that I need to extend it to an arbitrary depth of nested instances.  I can't figure out a good way to make this work with a for loop.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, note that converting a string to a variable name in the global namespace has been well addressed, but none of the answers seem to apply here.

EDIT1: I'll try to explain why I'm doing this, and let me know if I do a poor job of explaining.  I am using scipy.optimize.fmin, and I have been using only 4 parameters for optimzation. However, I now want to expand my optimization code to handle an arbitrary number of parameters, some of which are nested attributes several layers into the class/instance hierarchy.  I want to be able to create a list or dictionary at the top level to tell fmin how to unpack the parameter array for setting the nested attributes.

Comment: You should tell us what you're actually trying to do, since unless you are doing some very esoteric programming, "string typing" is almost always the wrong thing to do, and there's probably a much simpler way to do it.

Comment: See EDIT1.  If you can propose a better way to do this, I'll appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Anyone got any thoughts about EDIT1?

Comment: I wrote down my answer because I did not think it was possible to do anything better.

Comment: Ah, I didn't like the string typing either so I was hoping for something better, but this seems to work well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`operator.attrgetter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) to get nested attributes by specifying an attribute name containing dots (requires Python 2.6+):

> After `f = attrgetter('date.month')`, the call `f(b)` returns `b.date.month`.

For convenience, you can create a pair of helper functions:

```
def get_nested_attr(vars_dict, attrs):
    inst = vars_dict[attrs[0]]
    return operator.attrgetter('.'.join(attrs[1:]))(inst)

def set_nested_attr(vars_dict, attrs, value):
    setattr(get_nested_attr(vars_dict, attrs[0:-1]), attrs[-1], value)
```

Here's a complete example (tested with Python 2.7.2):

```
import operator

class MyNestedClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.att1 = 5.

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_nested_inst = MyNestedClass()

def get_nested_attr(vars_dict, attrs):
    inst = vars_dict[attrs[0]]
    return operator.attrgetter('.'.join(attrs[1:]))(inst)

def set_nested_attr(vars_dict, attrs, value):
    setattr(get_nested_attr(vars_dict, attrs[0:-1]), attrs[-1], value)


my_inst = MyClass()
my_list = ['my_inst','my_nested_inst','att1']

assert(my_inst.my_nested_inst.att1 == 5.)
set_nested_attr(vars(), my_list, 10.)
assert(my_inst.my_nested_inst.att1 == 10.)
```

Comment: Ah cute, this answer is basically saying that the function you desire has already been written for you; apparently `operator.attrgetter` will accept arguments of the form `"date.month.etc"` and return `obj.date.month.etc`. I would quote that part of the docs in your answer; I almost downvoted before I saw the `'.'.join(...)`. =)

Comment: @ninjagecko: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated my response to improve clarity.

Comment: @ninjagecko, good call.  I did not need to write any new functions, and this works beautifully.  I also am just using a list of strings without any need for the join mess.

Comment: I ran in to an interesting problem.  If I do `setattr(my_inst, 'my_nested_inst.att1', 44.)` then `my_inst.__dict__['my_nested_inst.att1']` is 44., but `my_inst.my_nested_inst.__dict__['att1']` is still 10. Maybe the lists are a necessary means of getting around this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the last `)` in your `vars...` was a typo, you have various choices for implementing a function like:

```
def namespace(names):
    """
        returns vars(vars(..vars(locals())[names[0]])..[names[-2]])[names[-1]]
    """
```

- Use `reduce` (as someone wrote in an answer which he then deleted...)
- A recursive function
- A function which explicitly uses a stack and a while-loop

---

Perhaps the easiest to understand is the recursive implementation:

```
def namespace(myList):
    if len(myList)==0:
        return locals()
    else:
        oneLevelUp = namespace(myList[:-1])
        return vars(oneLevelUp[myList[-1]])
```

---

The reduce implementation equally elegant. Here's how `reduce` works:

```
>>> functools.reduce(lambda a,b:[a,b], range(4), 'x')
[[[['x', 0], 1], 2], 3]
```

The implementation:

```
def namespace(myList):
    return reduce(lambda ns,item:vars(ns[item]), myList, locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, `attrgetter` doesn't work the way I used it. You have to 
 use reduce or a loop.

Comment: I think your syntax may not be exactly correct, but this is the most elegant way to do what I'm trying to do, and I will use it!  Thanks.  Also, I'll post whatever I end up with when I get it working.

Comment: explanation of -1: This will not work because the OP has a chain of nested classes where `obj.obj2.obj3....attr` must be referenced. All `attrgetter('a','b','c')` does is produce the tuple `(x.a, x.b, x.c)`. `setattr` will throw an error that a tuple is being passed into it. If you use this you need to couple it with `reduce`.